# How do you launch a django functional test via the jenkins cartridge on openshift?

Tags: python, django, variables, jenkins, openshift

I followed this https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-continuous-integration.html and set up a jenkins app for an existing app (Django 1.7).

Via the jenkins config I added `python ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}manage.py test` to the "Execute Shell" step.

Now, when I attempt to deploy my app I get the following error:
"KeyError: 'OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME'"

Having settings.py print all of the environment variables confirms that all of the DB variables are missing.

Shouldn’t Jenkins have the needed variables?

Comment: Here is a snippet of the shell command
`# Run tests`
`# python ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}setup.py test`
`source ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}python/virtenv/bin/activate`
`python ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}manage.py test`
`# Deploy new build`